# x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc: not found

Tags: linux, conda, miniconda, cpanm

I cannot install modules using cpanm inside conda.

```
cpanm --force Math::CDF                                 
--> Working on Math::CDF
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/C/CA/CALLAHAN/Math-CDF-0.1.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Math-CDF-0.1 ... OK
Building and testing Math-CDF-0.1 ... FAIL
! Installing Math::CDF failed. See /home/juan/.cpanm/work/1552930475.22685/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

The error is

```
/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc: not found
```

However x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc is in the path

```
(bio) ➜  ~ which x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc
/home/juan/miniconda3/envs/bio/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc
```

What could be wrong with cpanm or conda?

I'm using miniconda in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 6):

I also met this problem. Unfortunately, the answer of @tlsmy did not work, but set the thinking process. The path `/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/` indeed looks weird, and we would not expect the gcc binary file to be placed here. 
According to this [discussion](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10690#issuecomment-468489937) the problem is with the default version of perl on Conda-forge having the hardcoded path to the compiler. The @luvaul hack is to use other healthy perl version like this:
`conda install -c conda-forge perl=5.26.2=h470a237_0`
In my situation it solved the issue. Unfortunately, it has been at least a year, and this issue is still not resolved for all.

Comment: Thanks for this!  It seems that build of Perl within Anaconda has an issue and towards the end of 2020, it still hasn't been solved.  I guess the path to the compiler has been hard-coded somehow.  Unfortunately, if we don't specify the build, then the problematic one is obtained by default.  It seems build `h516909a_1006` from `anaconda` also works.  But I just checked `conda-forge` and their Perl's are more up-to-date!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`cpan` (which `cpanm` calls under the hood) is not so clever in respecting `conda` environments.

Open `~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm`. Change the line `'make_arg' => q[],` to `'make_arg' => q[CC=gcc],` should do the trick.